# VS2017: When building store package, bundle.upload file won't be created

Tags: uwp, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, appx

I try to build the **bundle.appxupload** file from VS2017 as I already did for several other projects. So the process in general is known and as far as I can see, there are no different settings to other projects. But somehow I get stuck this time.

I go to *Project/store/Create app package*, check to build a package for the associated Name, select to always create app-bundle, check architecture and run the process. After a while it completes with no error and the bundle is created and functional. Only the **bundle.appxupload** file is missing in the packages folder.

In my research on this issue, I found a command-line to run the process. For some reason, the file gets created that way.

`MSBuild "MyProject.sln" /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload /nologo`

Of course, this is a workaround, but I'd like to know, what happened to my project that made "the standard way" break. Also I'm not sure if the result really matches what VS usually does.

Anyone else ever experienced that?

EDIT: There was a typo in file-extension

Comment: Do you select create packages for side-loading option?

Comment: And please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/upload-app-packages), there is no such  `bundle.upload` in the app package folder.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT sorry! I edited already. The file is ```bundle.appxupload```

Comment: Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#validate-your-app-package) and make sure you have finished wack test for the app.

Comment: And please check if the package folder contains .msixupload file, and it could use to upload the package same as bundle.appxupload .

Comment: in the packagefolder an appxbundle is created. WACK is green too.
As I mentioned in my question, I do this on other projects on the same machine and the upload-file is being created. Only this project is a pain in...

Comment: Could you try to delete the old package and BundleArtifacts re-create again?

Comment: Thanks for your support! I tried. Deleted obj, bin and packages folder. Rebuild the project folder and the result is the same again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214873/discussion-between-mahobo-and-nico-zhu-msft).

Comment: I got your leave message, and this problem is hard to solve, we can't touch your .sln file, for this case please feel free open support [ticket](http://aka.ms/storesupport).